# File upload component sending two ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, reactjs

I'm new to react I've cobbled this react component together from different pieces i've found on the web. It's supposed to upload a file via ajax on submit. For some reason it's double firing. So when I hit submit my server is getting two requests instead of one.

Does anything stand out that a react beginner might miss?

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var $ = require("jquery")
var React = require('react');

var FileForm = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      myFileName: "",
      myFileHandle: {}
    };
  },
  handleChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({
      files: [event.target.files[0]] // limit to one file
    });
  },
  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = new FormData();
    $.each(this.state.files, function(i, file) {
      data.append('file-'+i, file)
    })

    $.ajax({
      url: "/api/content/csv/upload.json",
      data: data,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data) {
        this.refs.fileInput.value = null
        console.log(this.refs.fileInput)
        console.log(data)
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.log(xhr)
        console.log(status)
        console.log(err)
      }.bind(this)
    })

  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} method="POST" encType="multipart/form-data">
        <input ref="fileInput" type="file" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
      </form>
    )
  }
})

module.exports = FileForm
```

Comment: I've just try it in a plunkr and handleSubmit method is called only once.

Comment: @Dragu any idea why it would call twice on the server side? Perhaps it's an express issue?

Comment: Did you log to see how many times handleSubmit is called ? Do you see 2 identicals ajax queries in browser network?